# Error StackOverflow en java con base de datos

Tags: java

Tengo las dos siguientes clases:

```
public class Requerimiento_1 {
    int id;
    String url="jdbc:sqlite:ProyectosConstruccion.db";
    public void Metodo(){
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try{
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID_Compra FROM Compras WHERE Pagado='Si'");
            
            while(rs.next()){
                 id= rs.getInt("ID_Compra");
                 System.out.println(id);
                 
            }
            rs.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            
        }finally{
         try{
             if(rs!=null){
                 rs.close();
             }
             if(stmt!=null){
                 stmt.close();
             }
             if(conn!=null){
                 conn.close();
             }
         }catch(SQLException e){
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
        }
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Requerimiento_1Dao {
       public ArrayList<Requerimiento_1> requerimiento1() throws SQLException {
        Requerimiento_1 req1=new Requerimiento_1();
        requerimiento1().add(req1);
        return requerimiento1();
    }
}
```

Básicamente estoy trabajando con una base datos y me piden hacer un programa en java donde con 3 clases tengo que hacer un requerimiento en cada una. En esta me toca hacer el requerimiento que saque el id de las compras que si estén pagas. El programa entero maneja la arquitectura MVC por lo cual hay un controlador y Vista:

```
public class ControladorRequerimientos {
    // Su código
    Requerimiento_1Dao req1=new Requerimiento_1Dao();
    Requerimiento_2Dao req2=new Requerimiento_2Dao();
    Requerimiento_3Dao req3=new Requerimiento_3Dao();
    public ArrayList<Requerimiento_1> consultarRequerimiento1() throws SQLException {
        return req1.requerimiento1();
    }

    public ArrayList<Requerimiento_2> consultarRequerimiento2() throws SQLException {
        return req2.requerimiento2();
    }
    public ArrayList<Requerimiento_3> consultarRequerimiento3() throws SQLException {
        return req3.requerimiento3();
    }
}


public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Requerimiento 1");
        VistaRequerimientos.requerimiento1();

        System.out.println("\nRequerimiento 2");
        VistaRequerimientos.requerimiento2();

        System.out.println("\nRequerimiento 3");
        VistaRequerimientos.requerimiento3();
        
    }
```

La cosa es que cuando ejecuto el programa, me da un error StackOverflow en la linea

```
requerimiento1().add(req1);
```

De la clase Requerimiento_1Dao y no se la verdad porque. Además se que es muy probable que este cometiendo más errores pero apenas estoy empezando este tema y la verdad no se que podría estar haciendo mal.

Si alguien sabe porque da el error, le agradezco de antemano la ayuda y me disculpo por tanto código.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está aquí

```
public ArrayList<Requerimiento_1> requerimiento1() throws SQLException {
        Requerimiento_1 req1 = new Requerimiento_1();
        requerimiento1().add(req1);
        return requerimiento1();
}
```

Más concretamente

```
 requerimiento1().add(req1);
```

¿Te das cuenta de que estás volviendo a llamar al propio método `requerimiento1()` recursivamente? A lo que sea que devuelve el método le añades `req1`. Pero tal y como está escrito el método `requerimiento1()` nunca acaba, siempre se está llamando a si mismo y así una y otra vez hasta que se llena [la pila de llamadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_de_llamadas) de funciones y se genera la excepción de StackOverflow.

Me da la sensación de que esto es lo que quieres hacer

```
public ArrayList<Requerimiento_1> agregarRequerimiento1() throws SQLException {
            Requerimiento_1 req1 = new Requerimiento_1();
            listaRequerimientos.add(req1);
            return listaRequerimientos;
   }
```

Si te fijas lo que estoy devolviendo es una lista y no volviendo a invocar al propio método hasta el infinito. Por otra parte, procura que los nombres de métodos de las clase comiencen por un verbo y sean representativos de la acción. Esta es una de las convenciones de la Programación Orientada a Objetos en general y de java en particular.